# How can I use the input from an installer radio button dialog as a variable for part of a file system DefaultLocation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, windows-installer, setup-project

I have a file that I want to place within a certain folder based on input from the user during the setup wizard. I have already added a Radio Button Dialog after the Welcome dialog, with options and values.  The ButtonProperty of this dialog is set to REVITINSTALLYEAR.  I want to access the selected button's value and use that value to determine the location of where I install one of my files as below:

DefaultLocation: [CommonAppDataFolder]\Autodesk\Revit\Addins[REVITINSTALLYEAR]

Is this possible and if so, could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I have just done something similar:

Create an installer class in a separate project and override the Installer method -

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class CustomInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        base.Install(stateSaver);
        string myVar = Context.Parameters["ParamName"];
        ........
    }
}
```

Build that project and add the resulting dll to your installer via a custom action (Editor -> Custom Actions, right click Install and Add Custom Action).

In the properties of the custom action, set the value of the CustomActionData item to:

/ParamName=[REVITINSTALLYEAR]

Then back in the CustomInstaller class, at runtime, myVar will equal the value in REVINTINSTALLYEAR and you can use it to set the value of DefaultLocation in the Install method.

I found [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/customize-user-interfaces-and-pass-user-input-to-installer-c/) and also [Custom Action Data Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/2w2fhwzz(v=vs.100)) useful in working out how to get the value from the dialog and use it.